# Non-functional .htaccess file & PHPinfo not executing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, debian

Very new to this stuff so please be gentle with me.

I'm running a server with **Debian8**, and using it to host my website, Teamspeak and a bit of file storage.

After moving my server files into /var/www/html and sorting out DNS-stuff my site is up and running - but the clean URL fix I used (with the .htaccess file) no longer functions. I wanted to find out if this was a mod_rewrite issue so I tried to check using a phpinfo.php file - which kept downloading in browser instead of executing.

My .htaccess file looks as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

# Hide .html extension
## External Redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,NC]

## ## Internal Redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html

AddHandler php5-script .php
```

Things I have done:

Installed PHP5.

```
apt-get -y install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

and then restarted Apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

I hoped this would fix the PHPInfo.php issue, but still no success, so I attempted to edit the .htaccess file using

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

I'm assuming this will work but my .htaccess file isn't functioning so I figured I need to sort that first.

I checked for Mod_rewrite using

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

and was informed the module was already enabled. Okay, not a mod_rewrite issue.

Further searching led me to find /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, where I changed

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to `

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>`
```

Still no dice! I also checked /etc/apache2/sites-available/ and found two files, 000-default.conf (which contains none of the above code) and default-ssl.conf (same situation). I also have /sites-enabled/ which for some reason just contains a shortcut to the previous 000-default.conf file.

I'm pretty much at my wits end now, I've Google'd this stuff to death and my poor knowledge of the workings of this stuff is clearly hindering my progress. Can anyone help?

Comment: Check if PHP module is loaded as well or not.